# angular am-time-ago from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular, and I wrote my custom directive. There, I want to render some template to the screen, and until now everything worked perfectly. Now, I want to use angular-moment directive *am-time-ago* in that template. But that part doesn't render. It looks like this:

```
'<span ng-show="isExecutedSuccessfully(file.ID)"> <time am-time-ago="findResultTakenTime(file.ID)" /> </span>'
```

Is it possible to use angular-moment from my custom directive? My functions that I added here are working well.

Comment: Please put your directive code.

Comment: Just solved it, as I posted in my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, forgot to put dependency when defining the angular app, this line solved everything:

```
var app = angular.module('application', ['angularMoment']);
```